# Nav bar link changes color on page refresh (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS/Bootstrap. I changed the color of a link on the navbar, however I'm having an issue where the original color (blue) of a link on the navbar keeps appearing when I refresh the page. It only does it momentarily, however I would like for it to not do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've added more information since it was requested. Hopefully this helps.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <div>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&family=Chakra+Petch:wght@300&family=Shadows+Into+Light&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </div>
    <title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="nav-bar">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="../../index.html">Return to Homepage</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Sections</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">...</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">...</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">...</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">...</a></li>
                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">...</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">...</a>
                    </li>
                <li class="nav-item ms-auto">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">...</a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #212529;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav-bar {
    background-color: none;
}

#nav-bar .active {
    background-color: #ff2d6c;
    border: 1px solid #ad1414;
}

#nav-bar .active:active {
    background-color: #ff2d6c;
    transform: scale(95%);
}

.nav-link {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: clamp(.625rem, 3vw, 1rem);
}

.nav-link:active {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: #ff8c00;
}

.nav-link:focus {
    color: brown;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #ff2d6c;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: #212529;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
}

h2 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Chakra Petch', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}


p {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.guide-links li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', cursive;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.purchase {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.store {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.purchase img {
    width: auto;
    height: 2rem;
    margin: .5rem;
}

.purchase li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.guide-title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #ff0055;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem?

Comment: It would be very helpful, if you share your code snippet or share stackblitz link. Thank You

Comment: I want to add that I tried testing this on other browsers and this is only happening on firefox when using the file locally. Also, I tested the issue with the webpage online and the issue does not occur either.

Is this cause for concern? If not then I may just close the question since the primary issue of concern is that I did not want it to display this way online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first be sure your custom css file loading after bootstarp class (if there is not, put custom css line in header after bootstarp css codes)

then if problem still there, you cand add !important to background-color to #nav-bar .active and #nav-bar .active:active class

like this:

```
.nav-link {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: clamp(.625rem, 3vw, 1rem);
}

#nav-bar .active {
    background-color: #ff2d6c !important;
    border: 1px solid #ad1414;
}

#nav-bar .active:active {
    background-color: #ff2d6c !important;
    transform: scale(95%);
}
```

Comment: I've added !important as suggested, however it has not resolved the issue. Also to answer your question, my custom css file is being loaded after the bootstrap css. It is located in the <head> just below the bootstrap css.

Something to note: The blue color also appears on the links beside it (these are text links. Their color is white but on refresh it shows blue text momentarily just like the button's background color)

Comment: what is your browser? did you try another browser? sometimes some browser extensions cause that problem.

Comment: Firefox. It only happens locally though. It does not happen if I use the actual website. I checked and it seems to be working perfectly while online. The strange thing is that it's only happening on firefox. Is this cause for concern? If not then I will close the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you including your css file? It sounds like it's being included after this page has been rendered causing there to be a delay in your styling being applied.

Comment: The css file is placed after the boostrap css. It's being included in the <head>.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with :visited and there experiment with colors :)

Comment: This did not work. However, interestingly, now when I refresh I'll get 3 colors that quickly cycle between each other.
(I changed the :visited color to green to test it and it cycles green, blue, pink, and back to green)

Maybe this can help provide more information on what may be causing this.

Comment: Although this did not work. It did trigger a thought to check :focus. This solved another blue text issue I was having after clicking and moving the mouse away. Thank you for this! (I tried to upvote, however it wont let me due to my low rep)